# Comparing two hidden input with simple javascript failed

Tags: javascript, php, html, algorithm, hidden-field

I got two hidden input HTML that I want to compare with javascript onclick submit button.  But it won't work even though it seems simple and straightforward.

The function is:

```
function check() {
  if ((parseFloat(document.getElementById("price_sell").value) < (parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value)*0.95)) OR (parseFloat(document.getElementById("price_sell").value) > (parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value)*1.05)) ){
     alert("too high/low!");
  }
}
```

And the input text is as follow:

```
    <input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="<?php echo $prc ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="price_sell" name="price_sell" />
```

I have check the hidden input value and even though the 'price_sell' is twice as big/small as the 'price', the alert won't fire.  What is wrong with it?

Comment: Where is the value set for input tag having id `price_sell`?..If nothing is specified, then `(parseFloat(document.getElementById("price_sell").value)` will return `NaN`

Comment: first add value in price_sell. then try again. for testing purpose make them text filed.

Comment: And, there is nothing like `OR` literal in javascript...you should use `||` , known as logical OR operator...

Comment: Value is there, I have check by unhidden the <input> by making it text field,  It was filled by another function.  OK will try  II.

Comment: Hi, it still didn't work.  I am puzzled.  I will post a sample picture.

Comment: It turn out the onClick function never activated.  I change it with simple function that alert user and call that function with onclick at input type submit and it also don't work.  I am really puzzle here, another page work OK.

Answer (score 0):

Change the operator OR to ||.
This code, if was JS code, doesn't work because syntax error.

Comment: Change the OR with || but still does not work.  It won't fire the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Use Number(variable) to convert text to number and then do your comparing maths.

Example:-

```
var price = Number(document.getElementById(price).value);
var price_sell = Number(document.getElementById(price_sell).value);
var compare = price_sell - price;
```

Or you can check the variable type, using typeof

If value is `null` or `undefined` then Number function will convert it to 0 (zero).

Even though the 'price_sell' is twice as big/small as the 'price'-

### Updated Answer 2:

```
/*
Errors - price = '10 $'; means remove currency symbols 
         or characters from price_sell and price variable
Use trim() to remove whitespace.
I recheck my code, and found brackets missing, and posted again.
*/
price_sell = Number(price_sell.trim());
price = Number(price.trim());

if ((price_sell > (price/0.80)) && (price_sell < (price*1.30))) {
    // good
} else {
    // bad
}
```

Regards

Comment: this don't solve the problem. The principal problem is the OR, that must by ||

Comment: parsefloat won't do?  BTW, it still does not work even I change parseFloat to number.

Answer (score 0):

First as @Rakesh_Kumar mentioned set value to `price_sell` input field and try below code.

`function check() {
    var price_sell = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price_sell").value);
    var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value);
    if ( (price_sell < ( price *0.95 ) )  || (price_sell > (price*1.05) ) ) {
         alert("too high/low!");
    } 
}`

Storing the `price_sell` and `price` value in JS variables for better reading purpose . FYI there were some syntax error due missing brackets and usage of `OR` which i have replaced with `||`.

Answer (score 0):

> You must change the OR by || and add a value to price_sell

Test with this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="estilos/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function check() {
  var price_sell = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price_sell").value);
  var price = parseFloat(document.getElementById("price").value);

  if ((price_sell < (price * 0.95)) || (price_sell > (price * 1.05))) {
     alert("too high/low!");
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" id="price_sell" name="price_sell" value="4"/>

<input type="button"
onclick="check()"
value="Check">
</body>
</html>
```